# Multiple Sum using Linq (lambda expression)

Tags: linq, lambda

Its very straight forward, I'm trying to `Sum` both `Amount + Adjusted`

I'm sure its not the best approach to use.

```
var a1 = context.Employee.Select( a => a.Amount).ToList().Sum();
var b1 = context.Employee.Select(b => b.Adjusted).ToList().Sum();
var c1 = a1+b1;
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to create any lists (which will pull a load of data from the database, if this is LINQ to SQL or EF) - you can just use:

```
var c1 = context.Employee.Sum(x => x.Amount + x.Adjusted);
```

That's assuming you don't need the individual sums. If you do, I'd probably use:

```
var a1 = context.Employee.Sum(x => x.Amount);
var b1 = context.Employee.Sum(x => x.Adjusted);
var c1 = a1 + b1;
```

That's two calls, admittedly. This *can* be done with `Aggregate`, but it would definitely be uglier.

```
var both = context.Employee.Aggregate(
       new { Amount = 0, Adjusted = 0 }, // Seed
       (pair, emp) => new { pair.Amount + emp.Amount,
                            pair.Adjusted + emp.Adjusted });
var a1 = both.Amount;
var b1 = both.Adjusted;
var c1 = a1 + b1;
```

Comment: It is interesting, does `LINQ2Entites` take care of nullabe columns in this case?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Not sure. In LINQ to Objects it would ignore null values  when you use `Sum`, IIRC.

Comment: I'm not about ignoring null values. If the provider will generate something like `SELECT SUM(Amount + Adjusted) FROM tbl` then in case of nullabe column the result will be not correct.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Potentially, yes. As I say, I don't know what EF will do - I would always recommend checking that. (We don't even know whether these *are* nullable in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Jon Skeet's post here are some investigations related to topic.

Here the `ID` of `int` and `CustomerID` of type `int?`

```
Purchases.Sum(p => p.ID + p.CustomerID);
```

will be translated to:

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        SUM([Extent1].[A1]) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[ID] + [Extent1].[CustomerID] AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Purchase] AS [Extent1]
        )  AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

and

```
Purchases.Sum(p => p.ID + (p.CustomerID ?? 0));
```

will be translated to:

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        SUM([Extent1].[A1]) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[ID] + (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[CustomerID] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Extent1].[CustomerID] END) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Purchase] AS [Extent1]
        )  AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```